# How to update more than one Remote View in Android Studio Widget

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-widget

That's my code for the widget

```
class MovieOfTheDayWidget : AppWidgetProvider() {
    override fun onUpdate(
        context: Context,
        appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
        appWidgetIds: IntArray,
    ) {
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (appWidgetId in appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId)
        }
    }

    override fun onEnabled(context: Context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
    }

    override fun onDisabled(context: Context) {
        // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
    }
}

internal fun updateAppWidget(
    context: Context,
    appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager,
    appWidgetId: Int,
) {

    val randomMovieList = Constants.getAllMovies()
    val movie: AllMovies
    val randomMovieListSize = randomMovieList.size
    var randomPosition = Random().nextInt(randomMovieListSize)

    movie = randomMovieList[randomPosition]

    val idArray = arrayListOf<RemoteViews>()

    // Construct the RemoteViews object
    val movieName = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.movie_of_the_day_widget)
    movieName.setTextViewText(R.id.seriesMovieNameAndYearWidget, "${movie.movieName} (${movie.date}")

    val movieImg = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.movie_of_the_day_widget)
    movieImg.setImageViewResource(R.id.seriesMovieImgWidget, movie.moviePic)

    val movieRating = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.movie_of_the_day_widget)
    movieRating.setTextViewText(R.id.seriesMovieRatingWidget, movie.rating)

    idArray.add(movieName)
    idArray.add(movieRating)
    idArray.add(movieImg)
    
    // Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, idArray[0])
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, idArray[1])
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, idArray[2])

}
```

But the last 3 lines don't work properly, they only the second line works, how to update all of the `RemoteViews` in the `idArray`.
I've tried putting it in a for loop and updating `i`, but it also didn't work.
Is it even the wright thing to call the `updateAppWidget` function more than once? I've tried passing more than one parameter to the function but it returned an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, `appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget()` should be called just once.

You need to apply all changes to the same `RemoteViews` instance, so it should be:

```
// Construct the RemoteViews object
val remoteViews = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.movie_of_the_day_widget)

remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.seriesMovieNameAndYearWidget, "${movie.movieName} (${movie.date}") 
remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.seriesMovieImgWidget, movie.moviePic)
remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.seriesMovieRatingWidget, movie.rating)

// Instruct the widget manager to update the widget
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews)
```